# Why is my transistor switched on even though the collector is not connected

Tags: transistors

Newbie here. I bought a couple [BC547B transistors](https://www.datasheets360.com/pdf/-7845765891659071453?query=bc547b&pqid=105685813) to build some logic gates.
I'm using a breadboard which is connected to the 3.3V and ground from my [UNO Elegoo R3](https://www.elegoo.com/product/elegoo-uno-project-basic-starter-kit-with-tutorial-and-uno-r3-for-arduino/) controller.

I connected an LED to the emitter of the transistor. It lit up once I connect the power supply with the base pin, even though the collector was disconnected. I have followed [this other thread](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/171110/why-pnp-transistor-might-be-opened-even-though-almost-nothing-is-connected-to) and connected a high resistor (tried 100K and 1M) between base and emitter, which makes the LED glow really dim. Once I connected the collector it lighted up very bright again.

My question is: How can I fix this issue? Ideally I want to LED to not light up at all unless there is current on the collector. I already made sure that the transistor pins are two lanes apart each, but that did not help.

Comment: Draw a schematic.

Comment: in addition to the schematic, as Andy mentions, you can also include a picture  of your breadboard. The schematic does not have to be a real working (simulation) schematic, we just need to see some sort of drawing. Hand drawing is often also good.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> *My question is: How can I fix this issue? Ideally I want to LED to not
> light up at all unless there is current on the collector.*

Move the LED to be in the collector circuit (with the appropriate series current limiting resistor) and connect the BC547 emitter to ground/0 volts. Feed the base via a 1 to 10 kohm series resistor.

As you currently have it connected, the base-emitter junction acts like a forward biased diode and will supply the LED with current via the base. With the above proposal this won't happen.